# Deserialize array in xml C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

i have this Xml

```
<Facility ID="353">
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <Buildingtype>Test</Buildingtype>
    <SMSInfoID>
      <ID default="True">140</ID>
      <ID default="True">140</ID>
      <ID default="True">140</ID>
    </SMSInfoID>
  </Facility>
```

i have problem with desializing tag

I have tried many ways to solve it, and its what the last i have tested but still cannot reach the data inside this element.

```
public class Facility
    {     
        [XmlAttribute("ID"), Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Buildingtype")]
        public string CategoryID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SMSInfoID")]
        public virtual SMSInfoID SMSInfoID { get; set; }       
    }

[XmlRoot("SMSInfoID")]
    public class SMSInfoID
    {
        [XmlIgnore, Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public  List<ID> ID { get; set; }        
    }



[XmlRoot("ID")]
    public  class ID
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("default")]
        public string Default { get; set; }
    }
```

Can any one help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO NOT USE ARRAY WITH YOUR XML.  The array adds a extra level of tags. 
the code below matches you xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Facility facility = new Facility() {
                Id = 353,
                Name = "Test",
                CategoryID = "Test",
                SMSInfoID = new SMSInfoID() {
                        ID = new List<ID>() {
                            new ID() { _default = true, value = 140},
                            new ID() { _default = true, value = 140},
                            new ID() { _default = true, value = 140}
                        }
                    }
                };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Facility));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, facility);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

        }
    }
    public class Facility
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Buildingtype")]
        public string CategoryID { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SMSInfoID")]
        public virtual SMSInfoID SMSInfoID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("SMSInfoID")]
    public class SMSInfoID
    {

        [XmlElement("ID")]
        public List<ID> ID { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("ID")]
    public class ID
    {
        [XmlAttribute("default")]
        public Boolean _default {get; set;}
        [XmlText()]
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot control the xml, we recieve it from an service. 
No, nothing changed, still 
"SMSInfoID": {
    "ID": null
  },

Comment: it works, and i can see the elment is saved in the db, but when i try to return it, its embty

Comment: make sure you are using the instance of the class (facility).

Comment: i had to make this virtual to create the relation  public virtual List<ID> ID { get; set; }

Now its working, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the Id of SMSInfoID, you can rewrite it as a property of Facility:

```
[XmlArray("SMSInfoID")]
[XmlArrayItem("ID")]
public List<ID> ID { get; set; }
```

or wrap this property for XML:

```
[XmlArray("SMSInfoID")]
[XmlArrayItem("ID")]
public List<ID> ID 
{ 
    get {return SMSInfoID.ID;} 
    set {SMSInfoID.ID = value; 
} 

[XmlIgnore]
public virtual SMSInfoID SMSInfoID { get; set; }
```

If that's not a possibility, what can/are you allowed to change?

Comment: nothing of this worked !
and SMSInfoID is an elment and not an array

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `XmlText` to property `Id` to your class `ID`:

```
[XmlRoot("ID")]
public class ID
{
    [XmlText, Key] // <-- here
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("default")]
    public string Default { get; set; }
}
```